# How do you parse a file into a vector of tokens?

Tags: c++, token

So what I want to do is to create a c++ function which reads in a file and converts that file's text to a vector of tokens.

Now the text file I have requires many delimiters including periods, quotation marks, etc. so I thought strtok would work better than sstream to read in tokens. However when traversing through my vector i notice there is nothing in it. The code comes up blank. What am I doing wrong?

Please help me!

My code is here:

```
void getTokenFreq(string inFile_name) {
ifstream inFile;
int n = 0;
char *token;
vector<string> result(1);

inFile.open(inFile_name);

if (inFile.fail()){
    cout << "Fail to open the file tmp.txt.\n";
    exit(-1);
}

while(inFile.good()) {
    getline(inFile, s);
    char *str = new char[s.length() + 1];
    strcpy(str, s.c_str());
    token = strtok(str, " ’—\",;.:?“”");
    while (token != NULL) {
        result.push_back();
        token = strtok (NULL, " ’—\",;.:?“”");
        n++;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << result[i];
}

inFile.close();

}
```

Comment: "The code comes up blank". What do you mean? There are some errors here so it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: result.push_back(); [sic], try result.emplace_back(token);

Comment: Can you please post a complete example program that can be compiled as-is? Would make it much easier to help...

Comment: `while(inFile.good()) {` That's all well and good, but what you really want to know is the state of the stream after `getline(inFile, s);`. `while(getline(inFile, s)) {` gives you the best of both worlds. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are good, except some errors:

First:

```
vector<string> result(1);
```

Why would you have one empty `std::string` at the start? That would break your vector, and the result would be like: `"", "one", "two", "three", ...`.
Change it to:

```
vector<string> result;
```

Second:

```
result.push_back();
```

You can't call `push_back` with no arguments. With logic of your program, you should `push_back` the `token`, so change it to:

```
result.push_back(token);
```

Third:

You don't free allocated memory. After inner while, call:

```
delete [] str;
```

Also `std::string s` is not visible in your function, but I assume it is global.

Comment: Wouldn't mind knowing what earned this the downvotification. Yes this can be done with regex and some deeper stream parsing with a stringstream, but really

Comment: Actually this helped me! My program works perfectly. I have no idea why someone would down vote this because this is actually the solution. Thank you for your help.